# QGIS Attribute Table on print layout not sorting

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer, sorting

I've added in an attribute table to a print layout and am trying to sort numerically ascending using `Plot Order`

[image]

[image]

For some reason it doesn't change order whatever field I use to sort the items in the table.
It seems to be stuck sorting on `Feature_ID` which I can't edit.

I'm using QGIS version 3.14.16-Pi

Can someone direct me where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can solve it quite simple: Just add a double quotation `"` to fields having a whitespace in its title: `Plot Order` --> `"Plot Order"`. Then it recognizes the field correctly and sorts your attribute table correctly.

[image]